# Game on a string

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I am interested if one can design an efficient (polynomial) algorithm telling whether the first player has a winning strategy for a game described below.

The board is a string consisting of only pluses and minuses, for example: `---+--+`. There are two players. The players make moves alternately. In each move a player replaces two neighboring minuses with pluses, for example: `--+---` -> `--+-++`. If a player can't do any move then he wins.

Are there any papers on this problem?

Comment: Your game seems like it should map quite readily onto a varient of Kayles, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayles and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game .

Comment: A more general problem is the parking problem, of which discrete variants have been studied.  Check the Web for the continuous as well as discrete versions, and you may find a helpful survey.  Gerhard "San Francisco Has Many Such" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Answer (score 10):

From [the Wikipedia article on octal games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game) I posted in my comments above, I think your game is known as "Dawson's Kayles".

In case the mapping is not clear, a string of minuses and pluses should be interpreted as a set of heaps of continuous minuses.

Your example string of `---+--+` is thus a game position consisting of one heap of size 3 and one heap of size 2.

A move that replaces two neighboring minuses with two pluses removes exactly two tokens from the corresponding heap, say of size $n$ and divides it into either 0, 1, or 2 heaps (the sum of whose sizes is equal to $n-2$).

In your example move, `--+---` is a position with a heap of size 2 and a heap of size 3. The replacement of the last two minuses with two pluses removes two tokens from the heap of size 3 and results in a single heap of size 1; as you can see from `--+-++`, the result is a heap of size 2 and a heap of size 1.

While Dawson's Kayles has a complete analysis under normal play, under misère play (as you described in your question) it seems not to be fully understood yet, so I think nobody yet knows if there is an efficient algorithm of the kind you ask for.

From a quick google search, you can find more information and references in [this note of Plambeck's](http://www.plambeck.org/archives/dawsonsemigroup.pdf), though if you are unfamiliar with combinatorial game theory you may wish to start with some of the book references in the Wikipedia pages.  There's also discussion in [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615242/).